# How do I get convert an image to compatible hilbert curve data

Tags: python, math, hilbert-curve

I just started looking into the hilbert curve algorithm, and I want to convert an image into data that I can use with the algorithms. I dont have any code right now for display, but The code I do have is working and can plot hilbert curves on a python Matplot image.

Comment: add sample input in form you have? Is it really image or a polyline / polygon in vector form instead?  What is the expected output (hilbert curve filling of some boundary polygon?  Where exactly are you stuck?